# Array data to display in table cells where col and row are given in array

Tags: php, html, arrays, html-table

I have a array

```
Array ( 
    Array ( 
        [id] => 1 ,
        [schedule_id] => 4 ,
        [subject] => Subject 1 ,
        [classroom] => 1 ,
        [time] => 08:00:00 ,
        [col] => 1 ,
        [row] => 1 
    ), 
    Array ( 
        [id] => 2 ,
        [schedule_id] => 4 ,
        [subject] => Subject 2 ,
        [classroom] => 1 ,
        [time] => 08:00:00 ,
        [col] => 2 ,
        [row] => 1 
    ), 
    Array ( 
        [id] => 3 ,
        [schedule_id] => 4 ,
        [subject] => Subject 3 ,
        [classroom] => 2 ,
        [time] => 09:00:00 ,
        [col] => 1 ,
        [row] => 2 
    ), 
    Array ( 
        [id] => 4 ,
        [schedule_id] => 4 ,
        [subject] => Subject 4 ,
        [classroom] => 2 ,
        [time] => 09:00:00 ,
        [col] => 2 ,
        [row] => 2 
    ) 
)
```

I want to display it in table format according to col and row value

```
col 1 & row 1           col 2 $ row 1   
1st array data          2nd array data
Subject, room, time     Subject, room, time
1,  1,  08:00           2,  1,  08:00

col 1 $ row 2           col 2 $ row 2   
3rd array data          4th array data
Subject, room, time     Subject, room, time
3,  2,  09:00           4,  2,  08:00
```

I am new to arrays and need you support to sort this table.

Comment: Sort your array by row/col first, then iterate when it is already sorted.

Comment: I am sorry but i really have no idea as i am doing it first time. :( I tried $data = $rows;

echo '<table>';
for ($i = 1; $i <= 8; $i++) {
  if ($i % 2 == 1) echo '<tr>';
  echo "<td>{$data[$i]}</td>";
  if ($i % 2 == 2) echo '</tr>';
}
echo '</table>';

Answer (score 1):

```
if(count($array)>0){ // check if array has elements in it  
 echo "<table>";  
 // print table header  
 echo "<thead><tr>";  
 foreach($array[0] as $key=>$value){  
    echo "<th>$key</th>";  
 }  
 echo "</tr></thead>";

 // print rows  
 echo "<tbody>";
 foreach($array as $index=>$row){ 
  echo '<tr>';
  foreach($row as $key=>$value){  
   echo "<td>$value</td>";  
  }   
  echo "</tr>";  
 }  
 echo "</tbody></table>";  
}
```

for sorting you can try jquery plugin - datatables

custom sorting:

```
foreach($array as $index=>$arr){
 for($i=$index; $i< count($array); $i++){
  if(strtotime($array[$index]['time']) > strtotime($array[$i]['time'])){ // acsending order
   $temp = $array[$index];
   $array[$index] = $array[$i];
   $array[$i] = $temp;
  }
 }
}
```

Comment: I am using datatables but here i can't as this is timetable/schedule. So i can't use datatables

Comment: @Saleem then it depends what you want to sort by and where(client or server side). You can easily write your own sorting method.

Comment: Thank you Flame. I am new and trying to fine a way to handle this :) Client or server side any can i just want to be displayed as timetable

Comment: @Saleem updated answer with custom sorting by time in ascending order

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<table>
<tr>
   <th>id</th>
   <th>schedule_id</th>
   <th>subject</th>
   <th>classroom</th>
   <th>time</th>
   <th>col</th>
   <th>row</th>
</tr>
foreach($myarray as $row)
{
    echo("<tr>");
       echo("<td>".$row['id']."</td>");
       echo("<td>".$row['schedule_id']."</td>");
       echo("<td>".$row['subject']."</td>");
       echo("<td>".$row['classroom']."</td>");
       echo("<td>".$row['time']."</td>");
       echo("<td>".$row['col']."</td>");
       echo("<td>".$row['row']."</td>");
    echo("</tr>");
}
</table>
```

Comment: Thank you I need to add information to of 1st inner array to row 1 col 1. and 2 nd array to row 1 col 2. and onward :(

Answer (score 0):

Here is what i did to display results

```
<table id="TimeTable">
      <thead>
      <th style="width:20px; padding-right:10px;">No.</th>
      <th style="width:160px; padding-right:10px;">Monday</th>
      <th style="width:160px; padding-right:10px;">Tuesday</th>
      <th style="width:160px; padding-right:10px;">Wednesday</th>
      <th style="width:160px; padding-right:10px;">Thursday</th>
      <th style="width:160px; padding-right:10px;">Friday</th>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <?php for($r=1; $r<=8; $r++) {  ?>
            <tr>

            <td style="text-align: center; padding-right: 10px; padding-right: 10px;"><strong><?php echo $r; ?>.</strong></td>

            <?php for($c=1; $c<=5; $c++) { ?>

                <td><?php 
                    foreach ($rows as $row):
                        if(($row->row == $r) && ($row->col == $c)) {
                            echo $row->subject." <br />Classroom: ".$row->classroom." <br />Time: ".$row->time; 
                        } 
                    endforeach;
                ?></td>

                     <?php  } //col for loop ?>

            </tr>

        <?php    
                } // row for loop 
          ?>
        </tbody>
    </table>
```